# How do I format numbers differently based on their value in C#?

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have an integer that I will store in a string according to the following rules:

1. If the number is less then 10, then it should have a `0` before it.
2. If it larger than 10, store it without a leading 0.

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
String.Format("{0:D2}", myInt);
```

The ":D2" tells String.Format to pad the number to at least two digits by prepending zeros. If it's longer than two digits it won't pad anything.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ToString` with a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
var i = 6;
var stringRepresentation = i.ToString("d2");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find information on formatting numbers on MSDN at:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

One answer to your question is:

```
string formatted = myNumber.ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 2):

This site is a great reference: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

For your problem, you can also use this: `String.Format("{0:0#}", <yourIntegerVariable>)`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the string, you can write

```
str = str.PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Note that you might be looking for

```
string str = new DateTime(1,1,1, 12,34,56).ToShortTimeString();
```

This returns `12:34 PM`, and can be customized using [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 8;

string s = String.Format("{0:00}", i);
```

00 represents 2 digits
00.00 would represend 2 digits and 2 decimals